# SSH into secondary server and run multiple commands with putty

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I have putty configured to connect to `ServerA`.  Once, there I need to connect to `ServerB` and then do other commands on it.

In my remote commands textbox in putty, I have the following:

```
ssh testuser@192.168.1.114; sudo -u dev -H sh -c "touch ~/test.txt"
```

The first command works, but no matter what I put after the semicolon, nothing else executes.  Something about the SSH is throwing it off....I can run as many commands as I want if I leave out the SSH part.

I cannot use the intermediate proxy setting in the program as the server configuration blocks it.

Comment: Is the `sudo` command supposed to run on `192.168.1.114`?  If so, then remove the semi-colon before it, as currently it will run on the server you are sshing *from*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semi-colon does not do what seems to be attempted.

The semi-colon separates the commands.  So, on serverA, the first thing that happens is running

> ssh testuser@192.168.1.114

Then, after ssh completes (perhaps due to a failure to completely log in), then the remaining command will run on serverA.

> sudo -u dev -H sh -c "touch ~/test.txt"

In your particular example, check serverA for ~dev/test.txt

To accomplish what you're seeking to do, simply remove the semi-colon.  Wouldn't it be nice if all problems were solved so easily?

Comment: I think the key difference here is between _commands_ and _keyboard input_.

Comment: wow i cant beleive how much time i spent on something so trivial....thanks!